# Add two column heading on table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

How can I put "Chapter" and "Page" below Table of Contents title like shown in picture? And I also have to carry these into next pages in my thesis if toc is more than one page.Thanks,
[image]

And it would be great if they are not hyperlinked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My initial answer was written using [etoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc).

The main idea though, was taken over from [karlkoeller](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/27635/karlkoeller) [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159356/4686): using `afterpage`. The difference is that the method now is compatible with a TOC on many pages.

I figured next that it could be done in a simpler manner. Thus, I provide here two codes: one not using `etoc` at all. But the formatting of the toc will have to be done by some package, like `tocloft`. The second uses `etoc` to facilitate both the OP's constraint on the chapter headline and some formatting customisation. This second code sample has a somewhat more complicated document body. And on this occasion one sees something is not perfect for the last (fourth) toc page. I have not yet investigated which aspect of `afterpage` is causing this.

```
% without etoc
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[textheight=10cm]{geometry}% small page height for testing!
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\newif\ifintoc

\newcommand*{\PrintChapterTocHeadline}
  {\hbox to \linewidth{\textbf{Chapter}\hfill\textbf{Page}}\bigskip
   \SetupNextPage}

\newcommand*{\SetupNextPage}
  {\afterpage {\ifintoc\PrintChapterTocHeadline\fi}}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\PrintChapterTocHeadline}

\begin{document}

\begingroup\intoctrue
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\section{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

[image: toc page 1]

[image: toc page 2]

[image: toc page 3]

[image: toc page 4]

---

As this is done with Roman Numerals for chapters, some rather big spaces are used on the left.

```
% solution using etoc

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[textheight=10cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{afterpage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% doing the thing for the chapter  headline one each page.
%%%% here, using etoc.
\newif\ifintoc

\newcommand*{\PrintChapterTocHeadline}
  {\hbox to \linewidth{\textbf{Chapter}\hfill\textbf{Page}}\bigskip
   \afterpage {\ifintoc\PrintChapterTocHeadline\fi}}

% after title hook will take care of the first chapter headline
% nothing is written to the .toc file, hence other TOCs in the
% document can be done, not using that extra thing. Naturally
% the hook will have to be redefined
\renewcommand{\etocaftertitlehook}
             {\parindent 0pt 
              \leftskip  0cm 
              \rightskip \tocright
              \parfillskip -\rightskip
              \PrintChapterTocHeadline
              \intoctrue }
% etoc always typesets TOCs in a group. Thus the \ifintoc boolean
% will be false after the TOC completes.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% Now using etoc also to customize the formatting itself.
%%%% I take this opportunity to write down some rather general
%%%% etoc line style definitions, for a look somewhat like the
%%%% standard looks, but customisable.

%%%% some dimensions are hard-coded, but for some I already define
%%%% associated lengths

\newlength{\tocright}
\setlength{\tocright}{0.75cm}

\newlength{\toclefti}
\setlength{\toclefti}{1.25cm}
\newlength{\tocleftii}
\setlength{\tocleftii}{2.75cm}
\newlength{\tocleftiii}
\setlength{\tocleftiii}{4.25cm}

% Code for page numbers on the right side.

\renewcommand*\etoctoclineleaders
 {\hbox{\normalfont\normalsize\hbox to .6ex {\hss.\hss}}}

\newcommand*{\EndParWithPagenoInMarginAndLeaders}
 {\nobreak\leaders\etoctoclineleaders\hfill
 \nobreak\makebox[\tocright][r]{\mdseries\normalsize\etocpage}%
 \par }

% version with no dot leaders:
\newcommand*{\EndParWithPagenoInMargin}
 {\nobreak\hfill
 \nobreak\makebox[\tocright][r]{\mdseries\normalsize\etocpage}%
 \par}

\etocsetstyle{chapter}
{}
{\leavevmode\leftskip \toclefti }
{\llap{\makebox[\toclefti][l]{\bfseries\etocnumber.}}%
 \etoclink{\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\etocthename}}% roman uppercase
 \EndParWithPagenoInMargin}
{}

\etocsetstyle {section}
{}
{\leavevmode\leftskip \tocleftii }
{\llap{\makebox[\dimexpr\tocleftii-\toclefti\relax][l]{\etocnumber.}}%
 \textsc{\etocname}% small caps
 \EndParWithPagenoInMarginAndLeaders}
{\medskip}

\etocsetstyle {subsection}
{}
{\leavevmode\leftskip \tocleftiii }
{\llap{\makebox[\dimexpr\tocleftiii-\tocleftii\relax][l]{\etocnumber.}}%
 \etocname
 \EndParWithPagenoInMarginAndLeaders}
{\smallskip}

%\renewcommand*{\etoctoprule}{\hrule height 0pt\relax}
%\etocruledstyle [1]{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}}
\etocsettocstyle
  {\hbox to \linewidth{\hss \MakeUppercase{\contentsname}\hss}\bigskip}
  {}


\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsection{subsection}
\section{Test}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsection{subsection}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsection{subsection}
\section{Test}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsection{subsection}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\section{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsection{subsection}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsection{subsection}
\section{Test}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsection{subsection}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

[image: toc page 1]

[image: toc page 2]

[image: toc page 3]

[image: toc page 4]

Comment: Thanks. I follow your code and put the subsection and it is working great. Could you also share how to make uppercase for section?

Comment: @Aung are you using the first code sample (above the images) or the second one (below the images)? do you want also the sections to appear in uppercase? and finally do you prefer `uppercase` (in the roman font) or `small caps` (`\textsc`)?

Comment: @karlkoeller forgot to credit your `afterpage` idea! Later today I will rewrite the answer to more clearly explain how to achieve this without using `etoc`. Also, even with using `etoc` (which I employed initially also because of the formatting requirements of @Aung), the initial code can be simplified to work as in the sample below the images. I can't do that now for lack of time.

Comment: @jfbu , I just found out the second one is amazing. It is really clean. The second one works without needing to add for subsection. That's really cool.  I have an issue in Roman chapter Name. It is overlapped with the titles after chapter number six. If you don't mind , I would like to ask about chapter title in regular caps. I was able to get \MakeUppercase for "CHAPTER" but the chapter title still in standard form unless I use \uppercase{my title}. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Aung I have rewritten entirely the code in my answer, to more clearly explain that one can do this without etoc. But then you need some package to customize the other aspects of the toc appearance. I hope you can still see how to customise it to fit your needs. The chapter titles are set in bold face regular caps, the section titles use small caps.

Comment: @jfbu Can I also do the same thing for list of figure , list of table and list of scheme? At first , I thought if I could do on table of contents , I can do the same thing on LOF and LOT and LOS. But I think etoc is only for table of contents. Thanks,

Comment: @Aung `etoc` indeed knows only how to deal with the table of contents. The first method above however can I believe be adapted like this `\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\PrintChapterTocHeadline}`, for the list of figures, etc... you need then a package to customize the printing of the TOC, LOF, LOT etc..

Comment: @ jfbu Can I redefine "SetupNextPage" command again? I can switch between toc and lof but the only thing is it won't work on the next page of my list of figures because SetupNextPage is already defined for toc. Thanks,

Comment: @Aung good catch... the `\SetupNextPage` should have been removed entirely from the first method: `\newcommand*{\PrintChapterTocHeadline}{\hbox to \linewidth{\textbf{Chapter}\hfill\textbf{Page}}\bigskip
   \afterpage {\ifintoc\PrintChapterTocHeadline\fi}}`

Comment: @Aung you should presumably have conditonals `\ifinlof`, `\ifinlot` and associated `\PrintLOFheadline`, `\PrintLOTheadline` copied from the `\PrintChapterTocHeadline` we used for the `toc`, with `toc->lof` or `toc->lot`.

Comment: @Aung thus `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\PrintChapterTocHeadline}` becomes `\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\PrintLOFheadline}` etc...

Comment: Thanks. I should have look at your code carefully. Now I rename the newcommand like SetupPageOne and SetupPageTwo and now everything is working well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Aung great, if you find a working solution this way, perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Hoping your ToC won't span more than two pages, this works.

Add the following lines just before your first chapter

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{Chapter}{Page}{}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace*{15pt}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{\hspace*{-1.3em}\bfseries Chapter\hfill Page}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{\vspace*{25pt}}}
```

The first two lines add the required stuff in the first page of the ToC, while the latter two (with the help of the command `\afterpage` from the same package) add it in the second page of the ToC.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{Chapter}{Page}{}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace*{15pt}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{\hspace*{-1.3em}\bfseries Chapter\hfill Page}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{\vspace*{25pt}}}

\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That would help. I think people behind the thesis guidelines don't use latex. :)

Comment: @Aung I've edited the answer. Probably now it's what you were looking for.